# I don't understand the rules for calculating probabilities that use 'not'

Tags: probability

I've read the concepts multiple times, searched the internet, and tried to get a hold of my professor to no avail. I understand the probability of a complement rule as "P(not S) = 1 - P(S)". I don't understand how to use this rule when it comes to the union of two events. I'm giving an example I completed using my professor's previous answer to a similar question, which I don't understand the method to:

```
86% of all households have HDTV
49% of all households have DVR
40% of all households have both

b. What is the probability that the household does not have HDTV or does have DVR?

Let H = Owns HDTV, Let D = Owns DVR
P(H) = .86, P(D) = .49, P(H ∩ D) = .40

P(not H ∪ D) = P(not H) + P(D) - P(not H ∩ D)
but P(not H) = 1 - P(H) = 1 - .86 = .14
P(not H ∩ D) = P(D) - P(H ∩ D) = .49 - .40 = .09
P(not H ∪ D) = P(not H) + P(D) - P(not H ∩ D) = .14 + .49 - 0.9 = .54
```

Why does P(not H ∩ D) = P(D) - P(H ∩ D)? Can someone point me to material I can use to better understand these rules? Thank you.

Comment: Part of the problem may be that you ask about the union of two events (A or B), but your formulas talk about intersections (A and B).

Comment: As far as “material to better understand”, what’s the textbook in your course?

Comment: I’m convinced that I’ve posted an answer about this, perhaps on Math.SE.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Business Statistics: For Contemporary Decision Making, 9th Edition

Comment: Drawing a Venn diagram almost always helps.  You can find plenty of online resources about elementary set operations.  Here's one that showed up at the top of a Web search: https://www.smartick.com/blog/math/learning-resources/group-sets-venn-diagrams/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm some what confused by your notation, but if you're trying to figure out the probability of event $P(H \cap D)^c$ (meaning household doesnt have HDTV, DVR, or both), hopefully this will help...

Personally, I think this is easier to think about using the venn diagram below.

I've borrowed this image from: https://cdn.corporatefinanceinstitute.com/assets/venn-diagram1.png 

Let event X be the household has HDTV, and event Y be the household has DVR. 
So the X circle holds all the households who have HDTV, and P(X) = 0.86 
The Y circle holds all the households that have DVR, and P(Y) = 0.49 
The overlap of the circles represents households that have both HDTV and DVR, $P(X \cap Y) = 0.40$ 
The area covered by both circle X and circle Y is $P(X \cup Y)$ 
All the other white space represents households who do not have HDTV or DVR (or both), and is properly denoted $P(X \cup Y)^c$ or $P(X \cup Y)'$

So your question, "what is the probability that the household does not have HDTV or does have DVR?" is the white space, and can be calculated by:

1. Add the area of both circles: $P(X)+P(Y) = 0.86+0.49$ 
   and then subtracting the overlap of the circles (so the households with both are not double counted... 
   $P(X) + P(Y) - P(X \cap Y) = 0.86 + 0.59 + 0.40$
2. Take the total probability space, including the white: 1
3. Now we need to subtract the total area of households who have DVR, HDTV, or both... 
   $1 - (P(X) + P(Y) - P(X \cap Y)) = 1 - (0.86+0.49-0.40)$ 
   And we get the proportion of households that do not have DVR, HDTV, or both

$P(D) - P(H \cap D)$ Is the probability of a household only having HDTV, illustrated blow in the venn diagram by the section of the X circle that does not overlap with the Y circle.

[image]